# Refresh of a QGraphicsScene / QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, graphics, refresh

I am troubled by the following:

I am working with an interactive `QGraphicsScene` that needs to render the graphical representation of an SQL query, based on the users' operations, such as: add something to the query (a table, a new column, something else) or remove something from the query (a keyword, a table, a column ...). The changes of the scene must be displayed after the operation, and also the "logic layer" of the application needs to track the operations the user did, since the "rendering" of the query is done by the "logic" layer (ie: the "logic layer" creates all the `QGraphicsItemGroup` derived objects which at a later stage, after all the logic layer components were built, are being added to the graphics scene of the query and put on the window).

The problem that occurs is the following: right now I did not manage to find any usable solution to present a query after a change in the smoothest possible way.

Allow me to link in a screenshot for further explanation:

[image: Screenshot of the Query builder]

Let's suppose the user wants to remove the `PERSON.NAME` column from the query. What happens in the application:

- the user clicks on the "remove" (small red X after the column name) button of the `PERSON.NAME` columns' graphic item
- the Graphics View senses this operation, sends the REMOVE column from the graphic system to the "logic layer" (the "model")
- the logic layer on its turn removes the corresponding "logic layer" object representing the `PERSON.NAME` column,

And here the trouble starts:

- the entire graphic (yes, everything) is re-rendered by the logic layer creating the graphic items for the same query, without `PERSON.NAME`
- then I have to create a new window which has a new `QGraphicsScene` object together with a `QGraphicsView`
- insert the re-rendered objects' graphic items representing the query, (but now without the `PERSON.NAME` column) into the new `QGraphicsScene` with `addItem()`
- and now replace the central widget of the application with the new window.
- and now you can see, that indeed, in the query the `PERSON.NAME` is not there anymore and all the graphic elements that were below `PERSON.NAME` were moved up on the screen.

Obviously this is not a good solution, there is an ugly flickering when I change the window, but I simply did not find a better solution to this problem till now.

So I am asking for your help in order to identify what improvements can be done to this methodology of updating the screen upon removal (addition) of a new element knowing the background information above, without a new window. Obviously other, mroe generic graphic related comments are welcome too.

Thanks,f

Comment: If I get it right, you are not using the `QGraphicsScene` itself as your model, but a separate object structure which you use to recreate the `QGraphicsScene` whenever your model changes? And, even if this is true, what was the reason to not only recreate the items in the `QGraphicsScene`, but also create a new scene **and** a new view?

Comment: You get it right, I have to use my own model, in order to perform operations that go beyond the scope of the QGraphicsScene model (serialization, database binding, etc...). The reason which I remember was the main one to have to recreate the entire thing from scratch was that the QGraphicsScene took ownership of graphics objects which were created and referenced in my model and from time to time this lead to crashes because it decided that it is ok to do something funny with that object, and suddenly my stored pointers were pointing out in the wild. This specifically happened on redraws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information from the question and the comments, a couple of things you could consider:

First thing is that you need to **get rid of creating a new Window and a new `QGraphicsView`** when refreshing. 
I suppose this is the main reason for flickering. Keep your UI structure unmodified and only modify the scene.
You could use one of these approaches:

1. Either create a new `QGraphicsScene` and set it as the view's scene, or call `clear()` on
   the existing scene. Then recreate your `QGraphicsItems` from your native model and make sure that all your pointers and references are updated.
2. Another approach would be to have the `QGraphicsScene` **update** your native model when something changes, to avoid the need to recreate the whole scene from scratch. For example, let the `QGraphicsScene` handle the deletion of the `QGraphicsItem` when the user clicks the delete icon, and then let the scene update your native model to reflect this change.
3. Yet another approach would be to discard your native model, and use the `QGraphicsScene` with its `QGraphicsItems` as your model. Implement serialization etc. in the scene class. This avoids the need to synchronize the two models. The drawback is that your graphics independant logic is then much tighter coupled to the `QGraphicsScene`, which you might not want. Depending on your code size, this might also be a lot of work.

I would start with 1., since it seems to be the easiest way to go based on your existing approach. If you still come across weird issues with pointers and object ownership, try to isolate them and ask on SO :)

Comment: Excellent, 1 works very nicely... I call clear() and then addItem() but now it breaks the repositioning of the center of the scene from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416127/qgraphicsview-scroll-problem. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Unfortunately not, not out-of-the-box ... does the view scroll to any position, or does it not scroll to any position at all?

Comment: It does not scroll to any position, it goes back to the origin ... Anyway, thanks for bringing forward my small project :)

Comment: just FYI I fixed this issue by adding the horizontal/vertical scrollbar positions to the center. Now it's fine :)